# Ifconfig doesn't provide any Details on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, macos, vmware

Folks,

I have Kali linux running on VM machine..there are 2 interfaces configured on this machine..1 interface is configured as "share with my Mac" and the other interface is configured as "Private to Mac".And i believe "private to Mac" option will allow me to connect my VM linux machine to the local machine.... ifconfig command doesn't show any output. i have manually configured the IP address to both interface by editing vi /etc/network/interfaces and restarted the network services using the command "/etc/init.d/networking restart"...but still ifconfig doesn't give any result....

Actually i want to communicate on port ssh from my local machine to the linux vm machine..since the machines do not communicate each other.i am not able to work anymore..Can someone please have a look in this issue and let me know what changes are required to complete my requirement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `sudo ifconfig` ? If it doesn't work the problem could be the drivers of your network card. I'm not sure this will works but you can watch this tutorial [How to install network card to Kali](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4DcleXRTH0)

Comment: thnx for the response...